# Importing data from Ms Access to Ms SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, import

Does the database schema from Ms Access needs to be the same as the new one from the SQL Server when importing data from Ms Access to Ms SQL Server?
Lastly what is the simplest way to import data from Ms Access to Ms SQL Server?

Comment: `Need to be the same?`  What do you mean?  Do you mean the schemas have to be identical?

Comment: Importing Access is a common question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+%5Bsql-server%5D+import

Comment: There is also a guide here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/01/28/access-to-sql-server-migration-how-to-use-ssma.aspx - there's also a mapping of datatypes here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx that might be useful

Answer (score 0):

There are some datatypes in MS Access that do not directly convert to SQL server, and there are also some data types in SQL server that do not exist in MS Access - while most fields will 'upgrade' correctly, some may not.  For example, SQL server does not have a 'yes/no' datatype. the closest is Bit - but i would recommend using tinyint instead, as access will crash and have issues if you try and look at a null bit field, but it will easily recognize a null tinyint.  Also, when upgrading, keep in mind that True in Access = -1, but -1 does not work for tinyint, so you may have to go to int for that if you want to keep it at -1, otherwise you will have to change the values from -1 to 1(true in SQL) when you update it.

Also, SQL server has new datatypes such as larger datetimes that don't exist in Access - so most of your date/time values will convert into smalldatetime (precise to the minute) or datetime (precise to hundredths of a second), depending on what you need.

Using the 'upsizing wizard' may work in some cases, but i have found several times that due to corruption of the 'memo' types (or 'large text' in 2013 and newer) the wizard doesn't finish correctly.

Hopefully that answers the first part of your question.

As far as importing data from MS Access to SQL server, I have found creating a linked table within MS Access and writing an Append Query seems to do the trick well if you are not using both systems simultaneously.  If you continue to change the data within Access after you copy the data to SQL server, you can use a Append for new records, and update for old records, or just drop all data within the table, and re-append.

Hopefully that answers both parts of your question.